# How to pause for loop when pause button is clicked?

Tags: c#, .net

When I run the program and try to click the pause button, nothing happens. I am not sure how I can get this to work exactly. I have a bool variable called pause and pause is set to false. Once the pause button is clicked it should set that variable to true. Then the loop checks for that and should display a message to the user. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
namespace Practice2
 {
   public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    photocopier printer = new photocopier(500, 2500);
    bool pause = false;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (checkText(txtNumberCopies.Text) == true)
        {
            int numberCopies = Convert.ToInt32(txtNumberCopies.Text);
            int toner = Convert.ToInt32(lblTonerAmount.Text);
            int paperCapacity = Convert.ToInt32(lblPaperAmount.Text);

            if (toner <= 625 && paperCapacity <= 125)
            {
                txtMessage.Text = "Printer is low on Toner and Paper!";
            }
            else if (toner <= 625){
                txtMessage.Text = "Printer Toner is low!";
            }
            else if (paperCapacity <= 125)
            {
                txtMessage.Text = "Printer Paper is low!";
            }
            else
            {
                txtMessage.Text = "Printing...";
                txtMessage.Refresh();
                for (int i = numberCopies; i != 0; i--)
                {
                    int paper = Convert.ToInt32(lblPaperAmount.Text);
                    paper--;
                    if (paper == 480 || paper == 380 || paper == 400 || paper == 200)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("There is a paper Jam! Please remove the Jam and then hit the ok button to continue!", "Important Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);

                    }

                    if (pause == true)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Press the ok button when ready to continue", "Important Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                    }
                    lblPaperAmount.Text = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(lblPaperAmount.Text) - 1);
                    lblTonerAmount.Text = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(lblTonerAmount.Text) - 1);
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }
                txtMessage.Text = "Job is completed!";
            }

        }
    }

    private void btnAddPaper_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int paperAmount = Convert.ToInt32(lblPaperAmount.Text);
        if (checkText(txtAddPaper.Text) == true && paperAmount <= 500)
        {
            lblPaperAmount.Text = Convert.ToString(paperAmount + Convert.ToInt32(txtAddPaper.Text));
        }
        else
        {
            txtMessage.Text = "Printer paper is at capacity!";
        }
    }

    private bool checkText(string textBox)
    {
        if (textBox.Equals("") || textBox == null)
        {
            txtMessage.Text = "Please enter a value in the text box!";
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void btnReplaceToner_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblTonerAmount.Text = Convert.ToString(printer.Toner);
    }

    private void btnPauseCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pause = true;

    }
}
}
```

Comment: What I think you're saying is, you click btnStart, then while it's going you click btnPauseCancel and expect it to pause printing. Is that correct?

Comment: @DrewJordan Yes that is correct

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're doing the work on the UI thread, so the UI thread is busy and can't process messages (e.g. button click). You need to do the work on a worker thread instead, using `BackgroundWorker` or `Task.Run` for instance.

Comment: DO you have an example of how to use that?

Comment: @TylerStokes My answer is a bit easier to follow.

Answer (score 1):

A for loop is on the UI Thread so while the for loop is running you can't do anything with the UI. I suggest that you use a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` to do the job. You set the interval to 1 and that will run pretty quickly, but not as quickly as a for loop, though. But interval = 1 is enough for you.

Let me show you:

```
Timer timer = new Timer () {Interval=1};
```

to create a new timer object.
enter

```
timer.Tick +=
```

in the constructer and press TAB twice and that should generate an event handler. Write the stuff you want to do in the event handler.
Call `timer.Stop` to pause the timer and `timer.Start` to start the timer.